# Closed convex subset in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I got stuck on the following question.
Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $V$ is a nonempty convex closed subset of $H$. Prove that there exists a unique $u\in V$ such that $\|u\|\leq\|v\|$ for all $v\in V$.
I know that by proposition, there is a unique $u\in V$ such that for $h$ in $H$ but not in $V$, $\|h-u\|=\inf \{\|h-v\|:v\in V\}$. But how could I use this to prove this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you let h be the zero vector.

Comment: Circumcenter! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215202/show-the-existence-and-uniqueness-of-a-closed-ball-containing-a-bounded-subset-o

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias How to know zero vector is not in V?

Comment: *...for h in H but not in V...* It works for $h\in V$ as well, the optimal distance is trivially zero for $u=h$.

Comment: @Justin The element of smallest norm (i.e., closest to the origin) is not the circumcenter of a set.